# not able to run python manage.py migrate while I have some environment variables in the settings file

Tags: python, django

Am using 2 separate files for settings in my Django project one for production and the other for debugging,, here is how they look :

***base.py***

```py
"""
Django settings for arkb_eh project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/

"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['secret_key']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.environ['allowed_host']]

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',  # <-- Here
    'location_field.apps.DefaultConfig',
    'colorfield',
    'auth_system',
    'stations',
    'lines',
    'trips',
    'chat',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'arkb_eh.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'arkb_eh.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['database_name'],
        'USER': os.environ['database_user'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['database_pass'],
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
    ],
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = '/home/arkbrbyi/public_html/arkb_eh_last_back_end/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/arkbrbyi/public_html/arkb_eh_last_back_end/upload/'

STATIC_URL = 'arkb_eh_last_back_end/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/arkb_eh_last_back_end/upload/'
LOCATION_FIELD = {
    'provider.google.api': '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',
    'provider.google.api_key': os.environ['google_api_key'],
    'provider.google.api_libraries': '',
    'provider.google.map.type': 'ROADMAP',
}
```

***local.py***

```py
from .base import *

DEBUG = True


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

everything works perfectly until I tried to run the command `python manage.py migrate --settings=arkb_eh.settings.local` this return an error that means it cant open the Env vars data .. here is the error :

```
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['secret_key']
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'secret_key'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the variable `secret_key` is not in your environment. You should set it like this:

```
secret_key=abc python manage.py migrate --settings=arkb_eh.settings.local
```

Or like this:

```
secret_key=abc
export secret_key
python manage.py migrate --settings=arkb_eh.settings.local
```

Another option would be to directly specify the key in your settings file:

```
# settings.py

SECRET_KEY = "abc"
```